# How android save data in database sqlite in reinstall of application

Tags: android

In my android application, I use database Sqlite, and I enter some records in database from a file .txt, until this all are OK, but after a small period when I run my database, I find that there is no datas, so How can I save datas without be deleted in next run.

Comment: your code please so we can check it